# Git repository change scanner and check configuration has encountered a problem,

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink, adt

Got these errors after updating eclipse the current Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043

[image]

Tried lot of things but doesn't work, These errors are appearing frequently and not able to work.

Comment: So look at the error log like the message tells you and update your question with the details.

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Are you sure your Eclipse is up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. My eclipse was not updated. The following steps helped me resolve the issue. While in Eclipse:

1. Help -> Check For Updates -> Select all -> finish
2. System will ask to restart Eclipse, accept

Those steps worked for me.